# Missing dll's when using Py2Exe, PyGtk, and Glade

Tags: python, pygtk, py2exe, glade

I'm trying to build my first application using Py2Exe and I'm following the instructions listed at http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Py2exeAndPyGTK, with the exception that I'm creating the UI with Glade. (Its just a very minimal gui with a close button and a label.)

When I try to run the resulting exe, I get an error dialog asking me to check the log file which contains the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pygtkpy2exetest.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "gtk\glade.pyc", line 12, in <module>
  File "gtk\glade.pyc", line 10, in __load
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

So I started digging around a bit, the first thing that I noticed is that it looks like py2exe is not able to find glib modules:

```
The following modules appear to be missing
['gdk', 'unix', 'glib.GError', 'glib.IOChannel', 'glib.IO_ERR', 'glib.IO_FLAG_APPEND', 'glib.IO_FLAG_GET_MASK', 'glib.IO_FLAG_IS_READABLE', 'glib.IO_FLAG_IS_SEEKABLE', 'glib.IO_FLAG_IS_WRITEABLE', 'glib.IO_FLAG_MASK', 'glib.IO_FLAG_NONBLOCK', 'glib.IO_FLAG_SET_MASK', 'glib.IO_HUP', 'glib.IO_IN', 'glib.IO_NVAL', 'glib.IO_OUT', 'glib.IO_PRI', 'glib.IO_STATUS_AGAIN', 'glib.IO_STATUS_EOF', 'glib.IO_STATUS_ERROR', 'glib.IO_STATUS_NORMAL', 'glib.Idle', 'glib.MainContext', 'glib.MainLoop', 'glib.OPTION_ERROR', 'glib.OPTION_ERROR_BAD_VALUE', 'glib.OPTION_ERROR_FAILED', 'glib.OPTION_ERROR_UNKNOWN_OPTION', 'glib.OPTION_FLAG_FILENAME', 'glib.OPTION_FLAG_HIDDEN', 'glib.OPTION_FLAG_IN_MAIN', 'glib.OPTION_FLAG_NOALIAS', 'glib.OPTION_FLAG_NO_ARG', 'glib.OPTION_FLAG_OPTIONAL_ARG', 'glib.OPTION_FLAG_REVERSE', 'glib.OPTION_REMAINING', 'glib.OptionContext', 'glib.OptionGroup', 'glib.PRIORITY_DEFAULT', 'glib.PRIORITY_DEFAULT_IDLE', 'glib.PRIORITY_HIGH', 'glib.PRIORITY_HIGH_IDLE', 'glib.PRIORITY_LOW', 'glib.Pid', 'glib.PollFD', 'glib.SPAWN_CHILD_INHERITS_STDIN', 'glib.SPAWN_DO_NOT_REAP_CHILD', 'glib.SPAWN_FILE_AND_ARGV_ZERO', 'glib.SPAWN_LEAVE_DESCRIPTORS_OPEN', 'glib.SPAWN_SEARCH_PATH', 'glib.SPAWN_STDERR_TO_DEV_NULL', 'glib.SPAWN_STDOUT_TO_DEV_NULL', 'glib.Source', 'glib.Timeout', 'glib.child_watch_add', 'glib.filename_display_basename', 'glib.filename_display_name', 'glib.filename_from_utf8', 'glib.get_application_name', 'glib.get_current_time', 'glib.get_prgname', 'glib.glib_version', 'glib.idle_add', 'glib.io_add_watch', 'glib.main_context_default', 'glib.main_depth', 'glib.markup_escape_text', 'glib.set_application_name', 'glib.set_prgname', 'glib.source_remove', 'glib.spawn_async', 'glib.timeout_add', 'glib.timeout_add_seconds', 'glib.uri_list_extract_uris']
```

If I try to manually add the glib module to the "includes" option in setyp.py it doesn't have any effect.

Digging further, I opened up the resulting exe with Dependency Walker, it shows me that there are two dll's missing, MPR.DLL and SHLWAPI.DLL, but both of these are in my system32 folder.

If I just create the UI without glade, I have no problems what so ever, but given that I've already created another application with glade, I'd like to stick with glade if possible. Any suggestions on where to go from here? I'm using Python 2.7, Py2Exe 0.6.9, PyGtk 2.22.6 on Windows XP.

Thanks,
Brent

Answer (score 5):

i'm also having the same problem, however after spending few hours in google, i manage to find the solution.

1. use dependencywalker and profiling ur xxx.exe
   u can download from http://www.dependencywalker.com/
2. find out the error file (for my case, they are MSJAVA.DLL and libxml2-2.dll)
3. search ur pc directory and copy them into 'dist' folder. u also can download the missing DLL from other website.
4. run the dependencywalker again, u will see the error reduce or become no more.
5. xxx.exe is executable now.

I hope above would helps those who are facing such kind of problem.

Neoh !!!share is care!!!

Comment: +1 for `libxml2-2.dll`; adding that to the dist folder worked for me. Oddly, it runs fine without `MSJAVA.DLL`.

Comment: +1 for the dependency walker, but for me instead of adding the dll to the dist folder, adding the parent dll of the one with the error from the tree, to the `dll_excludes` of the option in setup.py make the app work (I added 'MSWSOCK.dll', 'MSHTML.dll' and 'DNSAPI.dll')

Answer (score 1):

This may not help, but I had the same issue & it turned out to be a gtk installation issue. This caused problems with the gtk._gtk.pyd file which py2exe produced.

The setup.py I used was pretty much the same as that which py2exe suggests on http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Py2exeAndPyGTK

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error once and fix it. when you run the `setup.py py2exe` your files are created in `win32`. `pyo` as `glade.py`o, and when you do you believe in `win64 .pyc`, at least that's what I experience, which ran the py2exe my `app in window7-64` and then gave me the error, but when you create the executable on `win32` I did, I think the `glade.pyo`, then gave me the same error, go to my project and do everithing with

> **gtk.Builder()**

` not use more

> **gtk.glade.XML("file.glade")**

and remove the import **gtk.glade** of my .py files and my **setup.py** just use

> **import gtk**

and everything worked perfectly.
I hope my experiences will be of your help.